# PHP call stored procedure retrieve specific table value

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have two table data in procedure.
This procedure run normally.

I use below PHP code only get table "temp_npdp_month_LOSE" data

How can I get table "temp_npdp_month_ADD" data using php ?

Thanks.

MySQL

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `npdp_procedure`()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM temp_npdp_month_LOSE;
    SELECT * FROM temp_npdp_month_ADD;
END
```

PHP Code -

```
//connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "CALL npdp_procedure();")) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo($row[0]."<br>");
    }
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: what is your php code output..?

Comment: Currently, I can only output TABLE "temp_npdp_month_LOSE" data.
I want to output TABLE "temp_npdp_month_ADD" data.
(or specific TABLE in procedure)